# Bash: Running scripts inside other script throws errors i don't get running them separately

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vi

Here's my problem:

I have 4 scripts to generate diverse files. I have a source file i pass as an argument to generate the other output files.
The 4 scripts are thought to be run consecutively.
They have code like this:

```
while read line; do                                                             
    if echo "${line: -3}" | grep -q ','                                         
    then                                                                        
        if echo "${line:0:4}" | grep -q 'int'                                   
            then ...
```

Running them separately give me the right outputs.
Calling them from a main script performs wrong, with some error messages like:

```
./FirstScript.sh: 35: ./FirstScript.sh: Bad substitution
```

Referring i.e. to the line above:

```
if echo "${line: -3}" | grep -q ','
```

My main Script to call the others is:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                            
sh ./FirstScript.sh $1
sh ./SecondScript.sh
sh ./ThirdScript.sh $1
```

All Scripts have been set to $chmod 755 *.sh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling them as `sh` even though your shebang points to `bash`. If you want to call them as bash just replace sh with bash , eg

```
#!/bin/bash                                                            
bash ./FirstScript.sh $1
bash ./SecondScript.sh
bash ./ThirdScript.sh $1
```

`Sh` lacks some of the features `bash` holds, which might be causing errors. See [Difference between sh and bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

 for more information about this.

Answer (score 2):

What is `sh` on your system?  Your `#!` line looks like you want the scripts to be interpreted with `bash`, but your main script is using `sh` , which may not be as feature-complete as `bash`.

Comment: It is by definition not as feature-complete as `bash`. Running `bash` as `sh` will disable many `bash` extensions.

Comment: That is one thing I still can't differ very well. Is Bash some kind of 'evolved sh script'? In that case how can I call them as Bash Scripts.
An why running them separately as 'sh ./xxxx.sh' works fine, but not calling them from another script

Comment: That was certainly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as I stated #!/bin/bash in the first sentence, I can do:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                            
./FirstScript.sh $1
./SecondScript.sh
./ThirdScript.sh $1
```

As it is said to run every executable with /bin/bash.